# Why can't I pass functions from Express.js to EJS like I pass other variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

Trying to paginate the posts I got stuck with passing `newerPosts` and `olderPosts` to the view. I am passing them just like the `posts` variable (and other variables):

```
exports.getPosts = async (req, res, next) => {
    //pagination params
    var perPage = 10;
    var currPage = req.body.page ? parseInt(req.body.page) : 1;

    const newerPosts = function() {
        currPage = currPage + 1;
        console.log(currPage);
    }

    const olderPosts = function() {
        currPage = currPage - 1;
        console.log(currPage);
    }

    const posts = await Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            } else {
                res.render('default/index', {
                    moment: moment,
                    layout: 'default/layout',
                    website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                    page_heading: 'XPress News',
                    page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                    posts: posts,
                    newerPosts: newerPosts,
                    olderPosts: olderPosts
                });
            }
        })
        .sort({
            created_at: -1
        })
        .skip((currPage - 1) * perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .populate('category');
};
```

In the view:

```
    <div class="px-1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick=<%="olderPosts()"%>>&larr; Older Posts</a>
    </div>

     <div class="px-1">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick=<%="newerPosts()"%>>Newer Posts &rarr;</a>
     </div>
```

Yet, I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: newerPosts is not defined` error message from the browser.

What am I doing wrong? What is the *closest* working alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:
make a new ejs file called `functions.ejs`:

```
<script>
  function test(){console.log(1)}
</script>
```

and then use `<%- include('functions'); %>` inside the template you are rendering. Use it at the start so that the function is defined when calling it.

In the corresponding route, use:

```
res.render('default/index', {
  ...,
  name: 'test'
});
```

Inside your template can do the following:

```
<button onclick="<%=name%>()"> <%= btnText %> </button>
```

BUT, when I look at the function you want to pass, I see that you want to change the state of your application by using `currPage = currPage + 1;`. This wont work, since as soon as the page is rendered there is no reference to `currPage` in the html anymore, cause everything is static html by then.

If you want to change pages etc. you will need to implement some frontend logic.

Comment: I can load them via Ajax.

Comment: Yeah you could do that, but it would add way too much overhead. Even from a architectural point of view I wouldnt recommend it, since you would be mixing view logic with controller/model logic.

Comment: What alternative would you recommend (with links to examples, if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
const posts = await Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
xxxx ... res.render()
})
```

I think here you need to make some changes in the logic of Promise usage ...
Think about - what happens if error appears ? where you handle it ?
and more interesting - after promise return result - where you exit from your function ? ...